# Search activity not being launched when pressing enter

Tags: android, searchview

Search activity not being launched when pressing enter.The search view is shown nicely on the action bar. But when i type the search query and press enter

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.punit.rateit"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.punit.rateit.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
              android:name=".SearchPageActivity">
          <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" /> 
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SearchPage" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name="com.punit.rateit.SearchResultsActivity"   android:launchMode="singleTop" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
     <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>       

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Here is the Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:com.punit.rateit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      com.punit.rateit:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
       com.punit.rateit:showAsAction="ifRoom"

       />

   </menu>
```

The activity which shows action bar.

```
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
     SearchManager searchManager =
             (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

      SearchView searchView =
              (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
      searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled (true); 
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

The SearchResult activity which should be the activity called when search submit button is pressed

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("search", "search triggered");
    setContentView(R.layout.searchpage);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("search", "search triggered");
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
private void handleIntent(Intent intent)
{
     if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.d("search", query);
}
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onSearchRequested() {

     Log.d("search", "search triggered");

     return false;  // don't go ahead and show the search box
 }
```

Comment: This is a good tutorial to implement searchable in android.
http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem. The tag

was needed to be for application .Removing it from activity and putting it under application did the trick.

Here is the latest application tag in manifest.xml

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.punit.rateit.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"           
            android:value="com.punit.rateit.SearchResultsActivity" /> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. There are two conflicting meta-data tags with the same name values.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work

U must delacre meta tag both in main activity (where you place the search widget and in the search activity)

Comment: Documentation tell different story..
To declare the searchable activity for an activity's search dialog, add a <meta-data> element inside the respective activity's <activity> element. The <meta-data> element must include the android:value attribute that specifies the searchable activity's class name and the android:name attribute with a value of "android.app.default_searchable".

Comment: I'm just baffled at how difficult this simple search thing is. I'm on my 3rd day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

After a long Research i have Analyse something

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new 
ComponentName(this,SearchResultsActivity.class)));
```

Here the activity.class is the name of the searchable activity where you want to pass the search query.

Comment: Worked for me. The documentation is very unclear about this. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog
Under the `configuring the search widget` section the comment says "Assumes current activity is the searchable activity"

So it basically is saying when the SearchableActivity is not the current activity it should be `new 
ComponentName(this,SearchableActivity.class)` instead of `getComponentName()`.
Very easy to miss

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and my search for an answer took me here, so here is what worked for me...

> Make sure your `searchables.xml` file is in the correct location (i.e,
>   in your `res/xml/` folder) and that the same file does not contain any
>   errors - otherwise you will find that
>   `(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE).getSearchableInfo(componentName)`
>   will return null, breaking your search functionality.
>
> (Also, ensure you set `componentName` in the appropriate manner,
>   because the example shown in the Android guide is for only when you
>   are making searches and displaying searches in the same Activity.)

...am sharing in the hope it may save someone else a wasted 4 hours! :/

Comment: I have wasted three days, today is the fourth day. Can you look into my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567796/android-assisted-search-the-search-button-does-not-invoke-the-searchable-activi)? May be you can spot the problem?

Comment: lots of time wasted, finally, this helps, though I'm still to figure why is it null.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a ComponentName object with the name of the Search Result activity class worked for me. Like this:

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchStoreActivity.class)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not using the strings within searchable.xml.

You MUST set it up that way or you will get null. I had just put in text instead of using @string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the problem for a day or two, it's not very clearly mentioned in the documentation.

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

> In the above the `getComponentName` function returns the name of the
>   current component, which is good if your current component is
>   handling/showing the search results, but if you have a different
>   activity then you need to put the component name of that activity for
>   search view to redirect searches to that activity.

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultActivity.class)));
```

Also make sure to have no errors in `searchable.xml` file in `res/xml` folder.